# How to generate "WP_Error" Object for user login?

Tags: login, authentication, wp-error

I want to return the Login Error Message even user key-in their privileges correctly. In other words, to terminate the login and show the error message.

When we key-in wrong passwords, wordpress shows:

```
There was an error authenticating your details.

ERROR: The password you entered for the username admin is incorrect. Lost your password?
```

.. on the login page. This is because of `WP_Error` Object is returned.

So my curious question is:

- How to get/generate this `WP_Error` Object on my own, to return back? Is it Array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to get/generate this WP_Error Object on my own, to return back?

```
$error = new WP_Error;
```

[It is fairly well documented in the Codex.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Error)

Once you instantiate the object there are methods for adding errors and for retrieving them, and functions like [`is_wp_error`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_wp_error) to check a variable to see if it is an error object or not.

Comment: Wow, like this?? Its cool!! `$user = new WP_Error( 'incorrect_password', sprintf( __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: The password you entered for the username <strong>%1$s</strong> is incorrect. <a href="%2$s" title="Password Lost and Found">Lost your password</a>?' ), $username, wp_lostpassword_url() ) );`